# Postgresql, escape character in string_agg function

Tags: postgresql, string-aggregation

**Question**, can I add escape character `\` just for fields `param_name` and `value` for this?

```
string_agg(distinct '{name:"' || param_name || '",value:"' || value || '"}',',') as "params",
```

Result is.

```
{name:"připojení",value:"1/2""},
```

I need this (use `\` before `"` only for fields/vars inside `"param_name"` and `"value"`, in case, when `value` has `"` character.

```
{name:"připojení",value:"1/2\""},
```

Thanks.

**Update**, no json, I need export to csv. Some code here.

```
copy(   

with recursive
cte as(
select
category_id,
category_parent,
category_name::text,
category_id::text category_ids
from s_category as c
where category_parent = 0
union all
select
c.category_id,
c.category_parent,
concat(cte.category_name, ' > ', c.category_name),
concat(cte.category_ids, ':', c.category_id::text)
from s_category as c,cte
where cte.category_id = c.category_parent
)

select distinct
s_product.product_id as "itemID",

...

string_agg(distinct '{name:"' || param_name || '",value:"' || value || '"}',',') as "params",
case when price_tax = price_rec then '' else 'Akce' end as "label"

from
s_product
left join s_cf_j_product_value on s_product.product_id = s_cf_j_product_value.product_id
left join s_product_image on s_product.product_id = s_product_image.product_id
left join s_pricelist_generated_lists on s_product.product_id = s_pricelist_generated_lists.product_id
left join s_producer on s_product.producer_id = s_producer.producer_id
left join s_category on s_product.category_id = s_category.category_id
left join cte on s_product.category_id = cte.category_id
left join s_cf_j_product_value as a on s_product.product_id = a.product_id
left join s_cf_value as v on a.value_id = v.value_id
left join s_cf_param as p on v.param_id = p.param_id

where

...

group by
s_product.product_id,
s_product_image.filename,
s_category.category_id,
s_pricelist_generated_lists.price_tax,
s_pricelist_generated_lists.price_rec,
s_producer.producer_name,
cte.category_name,
cte.category_ids

) TO stdout DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

It returns this.

```
... {name:""připojení"",value:""1/2""""},{name:""připojovací rozteč"",value:""558 mm""},{name:""rozměry"",value:""600 x 960 mm""}",""
```

But I need this.

```
... {name:"připojení",value:"1/2\""},{name:"připojovací rozteč",value:"558 mm"},{name:"rozměry",value:"600 x 960 mm"}","
```

Answer (score 1):

The doubled double-quotes (`""`) are the necessary consequence of `"` being the default quote character for `COPY` with `CSV` format. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

> `QUOTE`
>
> Specifies the quoting character to be used when a data value is quoted. **The default is double-quote.** This must be a single one-byte character. This option is allowed only when using CSV format.
>
> `ESCAPE`
>
> Specifies the character that should appear before a data character that matches the `QUOTE` value. The **default is the same as the `QUOTE`
>   value** (so that the quoting character is doubled if it appears in the
>   data). This must be a single one-byte character. This option is
>   allowed only when using `CSV` format.

You could use something like (assuming Postgres 9.1 or later):

```
COPY (...) TO stdout (FORMAT CSV, QUOTE '\');
```

Then double-quotes are not escaped.

To ...

> add escape character `\` just for fields `param_name` and `value`

.. you could simply `replace()`:

```
string_agg(distinct '{name:"' || replace(param_name, '"', '\"') || '",value:"' || replace(value, '"', '\"') || '"}',',') as "params"
```

Or:

```
string_agg(distinct format('{name:"%s",value:"%s"}', replace(param_name, '"', '\"'), replace(value, '"', '\"'), ',') as "params"
```

But `string_agg()` has nothing to do with either. And I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.